# Open MP : Symmetric matrix multiplication for Sparse matrices

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, sparse-matrix

I am working on parallelizing the Conjugate gradient method to solve sparse matrices. The CG method calls a subroutine "matrixVectorProduct()" in the algorithm. I am trying to parallelise this subroutine specifically. The following is the code I am working with for SYMMETRIC matrices stored in CSR format.

```
void matrixVectorProduct(MTX *MAT, double* inVec, double* outVec){

int i,j, ckey;

if((matcode[1] == 'X')&&(matcode[3] == 'S')) 
{
    //Initialize outVec to zeros
    for(int j=0;j<MAT->nrows;j++)
            outVec[j] = 0.0;

        for(i=0;i<MAT->nrows;i++) 
            for(ckey=MAT->row_ptr[i];ckey<MAT->row_ptr[i+1];ckey++) {
                j = MAT->JA[ckey];
                outVec[i] = outVec[i] + MAT->val[ckey] * inVec[j];
            }

        for(int i=0;i<MAT->nrows;i++) 
            for(int ckey=MAT->row_ptr[i];ckey<MAT->row_ptr[i+1];ckey++) {
                j = MAT->JA[ckey];
                if(j!=i)
                    outVec[j] += MAT->val[ckey] * inVec[i];;
            }
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\n Not a symmetric Matrix. CG method not applicable\n");
    exit(1);
}       
return;}
```

My code after parallelization is:

```
void matrixVectorProduct(MTX *MAT, double* inVec, double* outVec){

int i,j, ckey;

if((matcode[1] == 'X')&&(matcode[3] == 'S')) 
{
    //Initialize outVec to zeros
    for(int j=0;j<MAT->nrows;j++)
            outVec[j] = 0.0;

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for private(ckey,j) schedule(static)
        for(i=0;i<MAT->nrows;i++) {
            double zi = 0.0;
            for(ckey=MAT->row_ptr[i];ckey<MAT->row_ptr[i+1];ckey++) {
                j = MAT->JA[ckey];
                zi = zi + MAT->val[ckey] * inVec[j];
            }
        outVec[i] += zi;
        }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for private(ckey,j) schedule(static) 
        for(int i=0;i<MAT->nrows;i++) 
            for(int ckey=MAT->row_ptr[i];ckey<MAT->row_ptr[i+1];ckey++) {
                j = MAT->JA[ckey];
                if(j!=i)
                    outVec[j] += MAT->val[ckey] * inVec[i];;
            }
    }

}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr,"\n Not a symmetric Matrix. CG method not applicable\n");
    exit(1);
}

return;
}
```

The first omp pragma loop is working as desired. But there seems to be a problem when i parallelize the second loop similarly. It is not giving the correct output.

Can someone please direct me as to what I am doing wrong in the second pragma loop. I am a newbie to multithreading and open MP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a data race in your second loop since multiple threads can update the same vector element. Use:

```
if (j != i) {
   #pragma omp atomic 
    outVec[j] += MAT->val[ckey] * inVec[i];
}
```

which ensures atomicity of updates.